# how to use EventEmitter in angular7

Tags: angular, angular7, eventemitter

i define my component in one file and i want to send data form parent to child component in parent function is work properly but eventEmitter not emit

this is my component file have two component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject ,EventEmitter,Output} from '@angular/core';
    import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

export interface DialogData {
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-time-register',
    templateUrl: './new-time-register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-time-register.component.scss']
})
export class NewTimeRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    openDialog(modal:string): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RegisterDialog, {
            width: '480px',
            data: {name: modal}
        });
    }

    testEvent(value){
        console.log(value,"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'register-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'register-dialog.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-time-register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterDialog{

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RegisterDialog>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
    showAllPersons: Boolean = false;
    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    @Output() testEmit = new EventEmitter<string>();

    testEventEmitter(){
        console.log('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
        this.testEmit.emit("Test EventEmitter");
    }
}
```

this is register-dialog.html file

```
<span class="panel-title" (click)='testEventEmitter()'>Computicate Trial Account Manager</span>
```

here is my child app-new-time-register html file

```
<register-dialog (testEmit)='testEvent($event)'></register-dialog>
```

here is a child component

```
testEvent(value){
        console.log(value,"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to send the data from parent to child or child to parent?

Comment: `send data form parent to child component` not sure you get it right, `@output` is for child->parent .

Comment: EeshwarAnkathi i want to send data from register-dialog.html to  app-new-time-register

Comment: can you initialize @output like this and let me know the if it is working or not
 @Output() testEmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: YashRami its not work error show in console @output is not define

Comment: YashRami nothing error in console

Comment: Could you make an stackblitz example? It's hard to understand the files you have.

Comment: @DanielPiñeiro here is link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxim6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
and i want to send data from RegisterDialog to AppComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refering to your stackblitz, everything works with a little changes.

You have to add the `RegisterDialog` in the **app.module.ts**.

```
 declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, RegisterDialog]
```

Also in the **app.component.html** you have to add the `$event` variable to the emitter:

```
<register-dialog (testEmit)='checkEvent($event)'></register-dialog>
```

**Live example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55945887?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html